# How to get file path which downloaded with WebClient.DownloadFile()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, path, webclient

I am new in Web programming, so sorry for such question. I use `WebClient.DownloadFile(string fileAdress, string fileName)` method to download file. I get `fileName` from `fileAdress` (i.e www.somelink.com/file.txt => file.txt) . And now, i need to get full path of that file. If it was desktop application, somehow  i will find it. But now, situation isn't known for me.

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded file should be saved in your current directory. i.e., in

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/somefile.txt");
string filename = "somefile.txt";

new WebClient().DownloadFile(uri, filename);
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename);
```